# Clone metadata between Org to Org

Tags: metadata-api

What is the best way to clone metadata from one salesforce Prod Org to other Salesforce Prod Org? We are analyzing tools like Snapshot but looking for any alternatives so that all the metadata can be migrated at once.

Answer (score 0):

Force.com Migration tool is especially flexible. You can find the documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf). Another option with a more friendly user interface is to use Eclipse with the Force.com IDE installed as an add on. See [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) how to install and user. Both of them are free of charge so you can test them and see what fits your requirement.

Comment: agree mihai but our Org is huge and we will be ending up metadata api limits of 5000 components , also when i try to retrieve all the metadata components eclipse gets stuck :( so looking for a tool that can help to avoid these issues

Comment: If you cannot move all the components at once, you can manipulate the package.xml to only retrieve the components separately and then stage the deployment. For example retrieve all objects than all workflow rules, apex classes and so on.